# PGF variable content overwritten

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a pgfplots figure where I plot many curves and perform a linear regression on them to get the slope.
The LaTeX code I originally wrote contained the same group of lines repeated many times, with only a change for the color of the plot, and the name of the data to deal with.
So I tried to create a macro grouping of all these lines to simplify the code (and to facilitate the work if I want to change something !)

```tex
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data1.csv}
x y
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 7
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data2.csv}
x y
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 13
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread{data1.csv}\dataOne
\pgfplotstableread{data2.csv}\dataTwo

\newcommand{\plotAndComputeLinreg}[2]{
    \addplot+[#1, mark=none, dashed] table[x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=y}}]{#2};
    \xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
    \addlegendentry{Slope : \pgfmathprintnumber{\slope}}
    \addplot+[#1, only marks, forget plot, mark=+, solid] table[x=x, y=y] {#2};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \plotAndComputeLinreg{red}{\dataOne}
        \plotAndComputeLinreg{blue}{\dataTwo}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is an ECM of what I did, and here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the slope displayed is the same on both curves !
The slope of the red curve should be `1.8`.

I think it is because pgf set a new value to the variable `\slope`, and in the end, it displays the value it has in memory.
Is there a way to avoid that ?

======================================

**EDIT :** The answer below of @egreg answer to my initial post.
However I'm confronted with a more complex case than the ECM I gave, and I did not manage to adapt it.

In the macro I want to use, I plot 2 curves and compute 2 linear regressions, but I want to display the 2 slopes in a single legend entry :

```tex
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname-data1.csv}
x error_l2 error_h1
0 0 1
1 2 2
2 4 3
3 6 4
4 7 5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname-data2.csv}
x error_l2 error_h1
0 0 1
1 1 2
2 4 8
3 9 11
4 13 15
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread{\jobname-data1.csv}\dataOne
\pgfplotstableread{\jobname-data2.csv}\dataTwo

\newcommand{\plotAndComputeLinreg}[2]{
    \addplot+[#1, mark=none, dashed, forget plot] table[x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=error_l2}}]{#2};
    \xdef\slopeL{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
    \addplot+[#1, mark=none, solid] table[x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=error_h1}}]{#2};
    \xdef\slopaH{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
    \addlegendentry{Slopes : L2 \pgfmathprintnumber{\slopeL}, H1 \pgfmathprintnumber{\slopaH}}
    \addplot+[#1, only marks, forget plot, mark=+] table[x=x, y=error_l2] {#2};
    \addplot+[#1, only marks, forget plot, mark=+] table[x=x, y=error_h1] {#2};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \plotAndComputeLinreg{red}{\dataOne}
        \plotAndComputeLinreg{blue}{\dataTwo}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand `\slope` when you call `\addlegendentry` or the last meaning will be picked up at print time.

But there's no need to pass through `\slope` as `\pgfplotstableregressiona` would do.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-data1.csv}
x y
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 7
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-data2.csv}
x y
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 13
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableread{\jobname-data1.csv}\dataOne
\pgfplotstableread{\jobname-data2.csv}\dataTwo

\newcommand{\printslope}{%
  \expandafter\doprintslope\expandafter{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
}
\newcommand{\doprintslope}[1]{\addlegendentry{Slope: \pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}}

\newcommand{\plotAndComputeLinreg}[2]{
    \addplot+[#1, mark=none, dashed] table[x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=y}}]{#2};
    \printslope
    \addplot+[#1, only marks, forget plot, mark=+, solid] table[x=x, y=y] {#2};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \plotAndComputeLinreg{red}{\dataOne}
        \plotAndComputeLinreg{blue}{\dataTwo}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the more complex task, I suggest to use `\expanded`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname-data1.csv}
x error_l2 error_h1
0 0 1
1 2 2
2 4 3
3 6 4
4 7 5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname-data2.csv}
x error_l2 error_h1
0 0 1
1 1 2
2 4 8
3 9 11
4 13 15
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  legend cell align=left,
}

\pgfplotstableread{\jobname-data1.csv}\dataOne
\pgfplotstableread{\jobname-data2.csv}\dataTwo

\newcommand{\plotAndComputeLinreg}[2]{%
  \addplot+[
    #1,
    mark=none,
    dashed,
    forget plot
  ] table[x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=error_l2}}]{#2};
  \edef\slopeL{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
  \addplot+[
    #1,
    mark=none,
    solid
  ] table[x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=error_h1}}]{#2};
  \edef\slopaH{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
  \expanded{%
    \noexpand\addlegendentry{%
      Slopes: L2 \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{\slopeL},
              H1 \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{\slopaH}\hfill
    }%
  }
  \addplot+[#1, only marks, forget plot, mark=+] table[x=x, y=error_l2] {#2};
  \addplot+[#1, only marks, forget plot, mark=+] table[x=x, y=error_h1] {#2};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \plotAndComputeLinreg{red}{\dataOne}
    \plotAndComputeLinreg{blue}{\dataTwo}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, works fine for the ECM I gave ! Unfortunately, what I'm trying to do is slightly more complex (I though I could adapt what you provided, but I did not manage to do it...) I'd like the macro to compute the linear regression on 2 curves and display the two slopes in the legend in one line

Comment: @Thomas I can't guess what you really want to do.

Comment: I updated the initial post, I hope it will be more explicit

Comment: @Thomas Added a solution. Please, remove the previous comments.

Comment: It works fine ! Thanks for your help :)